# How can I change the instance name of a SQL Server from C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

How do I call the Stored Procedure sp_addserver from C# with the local switch?

In SSMS I can call add server like this:

```
    EXEC sp_addserver 'MYNEWSERVERNAME',local
```

My relevant code as of now:

```
cmd.CommandText = "sp_addserver";
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@server", "MYNEWSERVER"));
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This errors out as sp_addserver is not supported without the local switch.

Comment: Pass the other parameter too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sp_addserver supports the formal parameter called "@local".

sp_addserver [ @server = ] 'server' ,
     [ @local = ] 'local'
     [ , [ @duplicate_ok = ] 'duplicate_OK' ]

So just pass a parameter called 'local' with the value 'local'

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@local", "local"));

Answer (score 1):

Create your own SP that adds the extra parameters you need and then call that SP from your code.

Comment: I thought about doing that but I don't know quite how at this point.  Something I'll have to learn how to do.  Thanks @Neil